# Values fetched from database and assigned to variables do not persist across layers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this and the purpose is to set these Boolean values in the data layer with purpose of persisting these values in through out application's life cycle.

```
public class ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata
{
    public bool? SprcCustomIncludesInd;

    public bool? SprcCustomVariablesInd;

    public bool? SprcRatingFlowInd;

    public bool? SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd;        

    public static void SetFeatureIndicatorValues(string name, bool value)
    {
        ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata indicators = new Data.ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata();

        if(name == "SprcCustomIncludesInd") { indicators.SprcCustomIncludesInd = value; }
        if(name == "SprcCustomVariablesInd") { indicators.SprcCustomVariablesInd = value; }
        if(name == "SprcRatingFlowInd") { indicators.SprcRatingFlowInd = value; } 
        if(name == "SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd") { indicators.SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd = value; }           
    }
}
```

Then I have the data layer, pretty straight forward. I can confirm that database call is made and values are being fetched and at this level, the indicators are assigned values:

```
public void GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorsStatus(ProjectIdentifier projectId)
{
    ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata indicatorData = new ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata();

    GetSpHelper().ExecuteReader(
        spName: "ITV.usp_ProjectFeatureIndicators_GetByProjectId",
         parmsDg: parms => parms.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", projectId.Guid),
         methodDg: reader =>
         {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata.SetFeatureIndicatorValues(
                    "SprcCustomVariablesInd", reader.Column<bool>("SprcCustomVariablesInd"));
                ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata.SetFeatureIndicatorValues(
                    "SprcRatingFlowInd", reader.Column<bool>("SprcRatingFlowInd"));
                ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata.SetFeatureIndicatorValues(
                    "SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd", reader.Column<bool>("SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd"));
                ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata.SetFeatureIndicatorValues(
                    "SprcCustomIncludesInd", reader.Column<bool>("SprcCustomIncludesInd"));
            }
            return true;
        });
}
```

The application start up class calls middle layer through an interface. Below is hot it's implemented. The four 'vars' are just a test code but the bottom line is, values for the indicator variables are null. And I don't know why.

```
Data.GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorStatus(project);

ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata indicators = new ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata();
var sprcCustomIncludesInd = indicators.SprcCustomIncludesInd;
var sprcCustomVariablesInd = indicators.SprcCustomVariablesInd;
var sprcFactorSetsGenerationInd = indicators.SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd;
var sprcRatingFlowInd = indicators.SprcRatingFlowInd;
```

The `Data` object is class variable in the start up class:

```
private ProjectData Data
{
    [Pure, DebuggerStepThrough]
    get { return ProjectDataProvider.ProjectData; }
}
```

ProjectData is large class that holds lot of other stuff but my code only has this call to the interface:

```
public void GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorStatus(ProjectIdentifier projectId)
{
    _server.GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorStatus(projectId);
}
```

Then another class that has the following method that is the main logic for this task:

```
public void GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorStatus(ProjectIdentifier projectId)
{
    ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata indicators = new ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata();
    using (new WriteLock(_lock))
    {
        if (indicators.SprcCustomIncludesInd != null ||
            indicators.SprcCustomVariablesInd != null ||
            indicators.SprcFactorSetsGenerationInd != null ||
            indicators.SprcRatingFlowInd != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            GetProjectFeatureIndicatorsStatus(projectId);
            return;
        }
    }
}

public virtual void GetProjectFeatureIndicatorsStatus(Guid projectId)
{
    string PROJECT_SERVER_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConfigConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var configConnectionFactory = new ManualConnectionFactory(PROJECT_SERVER_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING);
    var projectFeatureIndicatorTable = new ProjectFeatureIndicatorsTable(configConnectionFactory);
    projectFeatureIndicatorTable.GetCachedProjectFeatureIndicatorsStatus(projectId);
}
```

Comment: What type of application is this? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Does your solution include an IoC container?

Comment: Best guess, a WPF. Application is launched as add-on in Excel. I don't think IoC container is used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand some of your code, like why in your method that has a DataReader, you make a new object instance of ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetaData but then you start looping the reader and make a bunch of static calls like:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata.SetFeatureIndicatorValues(
                "SprcCustomVariablesInd", reader.Column<bool>("SprcCustomVariablesInd"));
```

This won't do anything with the instance you just made, and you don't appear to access the static again outside the data reading loop, nor do you return the instance you made - you instead make another new instance in a different method and then try to access its properties (which will be null)

```
ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata indicators = new ProjectFeatureIndicatorMetadata();
using (new WriteLock(_lock))
{
    if (indicators.SprcCustomIncludesInd != null ||
```

Ultimately if you want your data to travel round your app you have to make an instance, fill it with data and then pass it somewhere (call a method and pass it as a parameter/return it from a method to a method that captures the return value). Right now you have some static things, some non static things and whenever you want to do anything you make a new instance, fill it with data and then immediately throw it away, or you make a new instance and try to read from it as though you expect it to contain data. It's like you expect statics to be some sort of defaulting mechanism that, once called, mean that every new instance you make of that type gets the "defaults" that were set by calling the static methods - statics aren't like that. Statics are more like "there is one instance of the static stuff, that the runtime makes for you, but to access it you must always use it in a static way(no instance variables, just the type name)" - you're mixing "new" (==make a new instance) with static(==a single already existing instance the runtime made)

I'd generally advise to stay away from statics as a way of passing data around; as global variables they're almost always a bad idea in potentially concurrent situations. If you're setting up a cache of commonly used data at startup they may make sense but it introduces a high level of coupling to your classes; every class becomes dependent on the static and has to know what it is and cannot function without it. If you code in a more Dependency Injection style where you give every class instance the data it needs to function when you construct it, you don't get to a place where all classes depend on one - instead they use the data they're given and it isn't mandated how it gets it - you can use that class in a future project just by dropping it in and providing the same initial data from a different way

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is an app that is basically a plug-in to Microsoft Excel. Basically a desktop app but not Windows form. I've never done anything like this. I do recognize that renewing the class instance is not working and agree with Global variables. I was under the impression that desktop apps would use some cache object that's native to the application framework.

Comment: Well they sort of do if you consistently use the static reference, then you're always referring to the "instance" the framework created when the app launched - your code's immediate problem is that it only refers to the static instance in the while(reader). You could think of the static instance as like "a cache"